# MTOM support ws:outbound-gateway

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-integration

We have a dynamic ws-service client, like this:

```
    <si-ws:outbound-gateway id="wsOutboundGateway" uri="{uri}" reply-timeout="120000" fault-message-resolver="wsFaultMessageResolver">

        <si-ws:uri-variable name="uri" expression="headers.URL"/>

        <si-ws:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <ref bean="wsRetryAdvice"/>
        </si-ws:request-handler-advice-chain>

    </si-ws:outbound-gateway>
```

is it possible handle mtom attachments in dynamic way, without a custom marshalling?
or for example it could, like this, but if answer have a mtom, we have another case for processing?

```
    private static class DefaultSourceExtractor extends TransformerObjectSupport implements SourceExtractor<DOMSource> {

            @Override
            public DOMSource extractData(Source source) throws IOException, TransformerException {
                    if (source instanceof DOMSource) {
                            return (DOMSource)source;
                    }
                    DOMResult result = new DOMResult();
                    this.transform(source, result);
                    return new DOMSource(result.getNode());
            }
```